# App gets terminated by IOS after some time

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have been working on an app which is basically a travelling app and it uses GPS and Location Manager. The problem is when i start the journey and keep the app in the background then after some time it automatically gets terminated and when i open the app again it again start from splash. Can anybody tell me that what is happening and How to avoid it.

For background Modes, I have used "App register for location updates"

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you analyzed memory consumption? If not that is the first step to do..

Comment: If you use CLLocationManager you need to make sure that it's actively updating the location with `[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];` when the app goes into background.

Comment: What do you mean by "get terminated". How do you know it has been terminated in the background?

Answer (score 0):

I understood because I also faced the same. Now what you have to do

1. Specify location background mode
2. Use an `NSTimer` in the background by using `UIApplication:beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:`
3. In case n is smaller than `UIApplication:backgroundTimeRemaining` ,it does works just fine, in case n is larger, the location manager should be enabled (and disabled) again before there is no time remaining to avoid the background task being killed.

   [Take a look this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/29948/backgrounding-for-ios)

and also look [Implementing Long-Running Background Tasks](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html)

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. If you register for significant change updates with CLLocationManager, you will be awoken periodically even if you app isn't running.

   [locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
2. Try using an accuracy of kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation to keep the app awake constantly in the background.  It's been a while, but as I recall the app does not stay awake in the background with lower accuracy settings.